# Deno: P selector in Deno-Puppeteer not working?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, deno, deno-puppeteer

The following code works fine in node's version of Puppeteer:
`const seletAllCheckbox = await pages[0].$$(">>> .datatable-select-all");`

The exact same code in deno-puppeteer throws a "DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '>>> .datatable-select-all' is not a valid selector." error.

The html is:
`<input class="datatable-select-all" type="checkbox"   data-navigation="enable">`

Any ideas?  Is the deno version incapable of dealing with P selectors? For reference, here is the Puppeteer documentation of P selectos: https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors#-and--combinators

I've tested both on the exact same page.  The node version works, the deno version throws the error.

Comment: Which version(s) of Puppeteer are you using? Running [mcve]s with the two deno and node scripts, the page being scraped, package.jsons and all relevant versions would be great. Thanks.